# Java extend and get inner class

Tags: java, class, inheritance, extends

I am extending a class and also extending it's inner class but I'm getting errors trying to get the inner class through the outer child class.

```
public class SMONArray extends SMONArr {

    public class Element extends SMONArr.Element {
        protected int x, y, w, h;

        protected Element(String string, Object arr) {
            super(string, arr);
        }
    }

    public Element getSelected(String key, int index) {
        return get(key, index);
    }
}

public class SMONArr {
    protected final LinkedHashMap<String, ArrayList<Element>> arr = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    public class Element {
        public String key;
        public Object elem;

        protected Element(String string, Object arr) {
            key = string;
            elem = arr;
        }
    }

    public Element get(String key, int index) {
        return arr.get(key).get(index);
    }
}
```

Like it is above I'm getting an error in the SMONArray child class `getSelected` function which is:

`Type mismatch: cannot convert from SMONArr.Element to SMONArray.Element`

Intellij suggests to cast the returned value to `Element` like this:

```
public Element getSelected(String key, int index) {
            return (Element) get(key, index);
```

But like this the error goes away and I can run the program, but when I call the `getSelected` function I get a different error:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: SMONArr$Element cannot be cast to SMONArray$Element`

If I don't extend the inner class I have no problems but if I do, how can I then get the inner class through the outer child class?

EDIT: The array `arr` in `SMONArr` is populated with `ArrayList` of `Element` of which `Element` is a `String` key and an `int[]` e.g. `key, [1, 2, 3, 4]` is what `Element` is.

```
intArr[j] = Integer.parseInt(strArr[j]);
linesArr.add(new Element(parts[0].trim(), intArr));
arr.put(key, linesArr);
```

Comment: Please show how you populate the map (or, specifically, the list in the map values). The CCE indicates that you're accessing things that are `SMONArr.Element`s, not `SMONArray.Element`s.

Comment: You have two element types.  You have a collection in the SMONArr class that can only hold one of the types.  The design needs to be fixed.

Comment: Aside: considering `SMONArray` does nothing more than extend `SMONArr` (confusing names, btw), why do you need the subclasses anyway?

Comment: @Andy Turner `SMONArr` is a generic class, `SMONArray` is extending it for use in this particular instance.

Comment: @access violation But how exactly would it be fixed?

Comment: @Hasen `SMONArr` isn't a generic class, it has no type variables.

Comment: @Andy Turner I mean it's 'generic' in that it's not specific, in the sense of English, not programming.

Comment: The key thing is how you create instances of `Element` that end up in the map. Please [edit] your question to show that. (Ironically, I suspect a solution to your problem may be to make `SMONArr` generic in the sense of programming, not English).

Comment: @Andy Turner Ok I edited my question to add that: The array `arr` in `SMONArr` is populated with `ArrayList` of `Element` of which `Element` is a `String` key and an `int[]`

Comment: "EDIT: The array..." sorry, I don't understand what this means. Show us the code, don't try to describe it. Somewhere you've got something _like_ `arr.get(key).add(something)` - it's the `something` you add that's important.

Comment: @Andy Turner It's an array of int `int[]`. Like `key, [1, 2, 3, 4]` that's specifically what's being added here. That's what `Element` is.

Comment: @Andy Turner  `intArr[j] = Integer.parseInt(strArr[j]);`, `linesArr.add(new Element(parts[0].trim(), intArr));`, `arr.put(key, linesArr);`

Comment: @Andy Turner That's done in `SMONArr`, the parent class, I thought that's what you asked. Most of the stuff is done in `SMONArr`, the parent class.

Comment: @Hasen where does that code live? It's significant, because `new Element` refers to different classes, depending upon where you put it.

Comment: If that code is in `SMONArr`, `new Element` refers to the parent `Element` class, so you can't cast it to the child element. Quoting snippets of code in comments doesn't have enough context - [edit] your question to show it.

Comment: @Andy Turner Yes I know, so there's no way to extend this class and get the inner class? That's what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @Andy Turner Ok so you just wanted to know if it was populated in `SMONArr` or `SMONArray`, ok I see now. Yeah it's done in the parent class.

Comment: Code executed in the superclass does not somehow use class definitions that exist in a subclass that the superclass is not even aware of.  Type definitions are not virtual in the same way that methods are.  If you want 'subclass Elements', then you have to arrange that 'new Element()' is executed in the subclass.  (Oh, now I see Andy Turner has answered to that effect. Good).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `createElement` class to your parent class:

```
public class SMONArr {
  // ...

  // Alternatively, this can be abstract (assuming you make the class abstract too)
  // then it has to be overridden in subclasses.
  public Element createElement(String key, Object value) {
    return new Element(key, value);
  }

  // ...
}
```

then you can override this in the subclass:

```
public class SMONArray extends SMONArr {
  // ...

  // Now Element refers to the subclass.
  public Element createElement(String key, Object value) {
    return new Element(key, value);
  }

  // ...
}
```

and invoke `createElement` instead of `new Element` in the parent class. Then the cast in the subclass will work without a `ClassCastException`.

---

You can do this without the need for the `getSelected` method in subclasses, by making the `SMONArr` class generic:

```
public abstract class SMONArr<E extends Element> {
  protected final LinkedHashMap<String, ArrayList<E>> arr = new LinkedHashMap<>();

  public class Element { ... }

  // ...

  // Now this has to be abstract.
  public abstract E createElement(String key, Object value);

  // ...
}

public class SMONArray extends SMONArr<SMONArray.Element> {
  public class Element extends SMONArr.Element { ... }

  public Element createElement(String key, Object value) {
    return new Element(key, value);
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You have two element types.  You have a collection in the SMONArr class that can only hold one of the types.

The call to 'get' in SMONArr class returns a SMONArr.Element, which is not a SMONArray.Element.

I don't know the context - perhaps in this case the collection is guaranteed to hold only SMONArray.Elements, in which case a cast would do the trick.

Comment: The get function in SMONArr is listed in my code above. I don't see how this answers how to 'get' the element. So basically you can't really extend inner classes?

Comment: You write the body of SMONArray.getSelected as `return (Element) get(key, index)`.  But this depends on the collection in the superclass only ever having SMONArray.Elements and never plain SMONArr.Elements, which I cannot know from what you have said.

Comment: That's how it is already..

Comment: According to what you posted, it is currently just `return get(key, index)`

Comment: If you read the entire post I stated I added the cast and it produced a different error.

Comment: Oh, I was looking at the code, not the subsequent talk.  Then you have a design problem. The array does not contain SMONArray.Elements (as evidenced by the cast exception), so you can't treat it as if it does.

Comment: No so like I said, it's not possible to extend classes with inner classes? I mean where I have an array which is on the parent class like this. You say it's a design problem but I can't see another way to do it. You'd have to put the array on the child class which wouldn't make sense or even work.

Comment: As asked by Andy Turner - how is it populated?  You are evidently inserting SMONArr.Elements in the collection.

Comment: The array `arr` in `SMONArr` is populated with `ArrayList` of `Element` of which `Element` is a `String` key and an `int[]`.

Comment: If it's populated in SMONArr, then it's populated with SMONArr.Elements, which are **not** SMONArray.Elements, as both Intellij and the cast-cast exception have said.

Comment: Yes of course, it can't populate with `SMONArray.Element` since that is defined in the child class, but the issue is how to fix the get method in the child class. No problem anyway, Andy came up with the solution yesterday.

Answer (score -1):

Your issue has nothing to do with extending the inner class, you return the wrong type and don't see it because of the naming confusion.

This is what you're doing:

```
public class Outer1 {
 class Inner1 {}

 public Inner1 get() {
  return new Inner1();
 }
}
public class Outer2 extends Outer1 {
    public class Inner2 extends Outer1.Inner1 {}

    public Inner2 getSelected() {
        return get();
    }
}
```

You `getSelected()` is declared as returning the subtype, but then you call the method returning the supertype.

You can change its return type to `Inner1`, or in your case `SMONArr.Element`.

```
public SMONArr.Element getSelected(String key, int index) {
  return get(key, index);
}
```

Comment: With your code like that you get the error `Type mismatch: cannot convert from SMONArr.Element to SMONArray.Element`

Comment: @Hasen then you copied it wrong, there is no conversion from `SMONArr.Element` to `SMONArray.Element` in my code, only the other way around.

Comment: OK I see what you mean, but like that surely it won't be getting the extended inner class? There'd be no point in me extending the inner class in the first place...